# Problems with JDBC connection for BigQuery with Java SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, google-bigquery, jdbctemplate

I am trying to add the BigQuery JDBC driver to my Spring Boot application but I am having some problems. I have downloaded the driver from the Google Cloud download page and added the dependency in my pom.xml file, but when I try to connect to BigQuery I get a "No suitable driver found" exception.

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:bigquery://https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2:443;......
> at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:702) ~[java.sql:na]
> at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:251) ~[java.sql:na]

I have added the drive as follows in pom.xml:

> ```
>   <dependency>            
>         <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
>       <artifactId>google-cloud-bigquery-jdbc</artifactId>
>       <version>1.3.0</version>            <scope>system</scope>
>       <systemPath>... resources/drivers/bigquer/SimbaJDBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery42_1.3.0.1001_JB.zip</systemPath>
>   </dependency>
> ```

I'm trying to get the connection in this ways:

> ```
> private  static Connection connectViaDM() throws Exception
> {
>     Connection connection = null;
>     connection = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_URL);
>     return connection;
> }
> ```

```
private Connection connectViaDS() throws Exception
{
    Connection connection = null;
    DataSource ds = new com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc42.DataSource();
    ds.setURL(CONNECTION_URL);
    ....
    connection = ds.getConnection();
    return connection;
}
```

The bigquery access data that I handle is correct because I am able to connect to the java client:

> ```
>         BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(PROJECT_ID).setCredentials(
>                 ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(
>                         new FileInputStream(KEY_FILE))
>         )
>                 .build().getService();
>
>
>         QueryJobConfiguration queryConfig = QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(query).build();
>         TableResult results = bigquery.query(queryConfig);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `SimbaJdbcDriver` for `Bigquery`, you can use a starter to use directly `Bigquery` client with `Spring Boot` app :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-bigquery</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

```java
@Autowired
BigQuery bigquery;

// Execute a query
public void runQuery() throws InterruptedException {
  String query = "SELECT column FROM table;";
  QueryJobConfiguration queryConfig =
      QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(query).build();

  for (FieldValueList row : bigquery.query(queryConfig).iterateAll()) {
    for (FieldValue val : row) {
      System.out.println(val);
    }
  }
}
```

Use `BigQueryTemplate` :

```java
@Autowired
BigQueryTemplate bigQueryTemplate;

public void loadData(InputStream dataInputStream, String tableName) {
  ListenableFuture<Job> bigQueryJobFuture =
      bigQueryTemplate.writeDataToTable(
          tableName,
          dataFile.getInputStream(),
          FormatOptions.csv());

  // After the future is complete, the data is successfully loaded.
  Job job = bigQueryJobFuture.get();
}
```

The following [link](https://blog.knoldus.com/spring-gcp-bigquery/) gives more information.

In `Java` (Spring Boot or not), you can also directly use the `BigQuery` [client](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-client-libraries#run_the_query)

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that I need to use JDBC in order to generalize a multi-database type implementation to obtain a ResultSet.